# UIDocumentInteractionController file attachment error

Tags: swift, swift3, uidocumentinteraction

so I'm working on exporting a .txt file from Xcode, but whenever I try to export it, say through email, it creates an email with no attachments and an empty message. When I try to export it to iCloud Drive, a white screen comes up for a second, then leaves. When I check iCloud Drive, the file isn't there. What is wrong here?

```
let message = testLabel.text

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> NSString {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory as NSString
}

let filePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("matrixFile.txt")

do{
    try message?.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}catch let error as NSError{
    testLabel.text = String(describing: error)
}

let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()
documentInteractionController.url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath)
documentInteractionController.uti = "public.data, public.content"
documentInteractionController.name = "matrixFile"
documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.frame, in: view, animated: true)
```

Comment: Swift 3 you should use URL instead of NSURL

Comment: URL(fileURLWithPath:) initializer. It would be better to get the documents URL and append the file name to it

Comment: @LeoDabus this didn't seem to do it. I tried making it `documentInteractionController.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)` and it still won't send any attachments.

Comment: to send email I recommend using MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193928/como-compartilhar-um-pdf-que-esta-numa-webview-em-swift/194238#194238

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193928/como-compartilhar-um-pdf-que-esta-numa-webview-em-swift/194238#194238

Answer (score 7):

The problem is you are declaring your document interaction controller as a constant within the method that calls it, like:

```
func someButton() {
    let controller = UIDocumentInteractionController...
}
```

It will not work like that. The interaction controller needs to be an instance variable of the class that presents it, and it should be reinitialized every time you present it with a new url, like so:

```
var controller: UIDocumentInteractionController!

func someButton() {
    controller = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: someURL)
    controller.presentOptionsMenu...
}
```

Why? I have no idea, but file a bug report if you think this is absurd.

Comment: Wow, that worked, thanks! This is very absurd and I can't guess why this happen. This is not logic.

Comment: It works because previously you were not retaining the controller, and it was being deallocated upon returning from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your UTI is wrong. For a text file you should use "public.text". But there is a constant for this already - `kUTTypePlainText`. You just need to import `MobileCoreServices` to use it.

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

then:

```
documentInteractionController.uti = kUTTypePlainText as String
```

You should also use the proper initializer when creating the controller:

```
let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
documentInteractionController.uti = kUTTypePlainText as String
documentInteractionController.name = "matrixFile"
documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.frame, in: view, animated: true)
```

And I would only create and show the controller if the text isn't nil and you successfully write the file:

```
if let message = testLabel.text {
    let filePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("matrixFile.txt")

    do {
        try message.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
        documentInteractionController.uti = kUTTypePlainText as String
        documentInteractionController.name = "matrixFile"
        documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.frame, in: view, animated: true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        testLabel.text = String(describing: error)
    }
}
```

Comment: the initializer doesn't make any difference if you set the url property. I never used the url initializer and it works for sure

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeah, that's a preference. The real issues are the wrong UTI and the possibility that the file is never created at all.

Comment: no need to import MobileCoreServices. only UIKit is needed

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, it's needed for `kUTTypePlainText`.

Comment: I have just tested the UTI `"public.data, public.content"` with plain text and it is not the issue. It works for any fite type as I said

Comment: BTW import whole MobileCoreServices for just a string makes no sense. why not just `"public.plain-text"` ?

Comment: kUTTypePlainText `"public.plain-text"` conforms to public.text that conforms to public.content, public.data https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html

Comment: @Leo The problem is the file isn't being written. Hence the last third of my answer.